# refactor age imputation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

How can I refactor the following code to make sure it easier to read and better using a function. Can reproduce code and data frames used using GitHub https://github.com/hamidpat/titanic posted csv used on my github.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


train_df = pd.read_csv("train_df.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test_df.csv.csv")
combine = [train_df, test_df]


guess_ages = np.zeros((2, 3))
for df in combine:
    for i in range(0, 2):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            guess_df = df[(df['Sex'] == i) & (
                df['Pclass'] == j + 1)]['Age'].dropna()
            age_guess = guess_df.median()
            guess_ages[i, j] = int(age_guess/0.5 + 0.5) * 0.5
    for i in range(0, 2):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            df.loc[(df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Sex == i) & (
                df.Pclass == j + 1), 'Age'] = guess_ages[i, j]

    df.Age = df.Age.astype(int)
```

Comment: you might want to explain the logic of your code (adding comments to it for example)

Comment: You can first consider adding comments to explain the meaning of your `for` loops, for instance. This will be for sure easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, what you want is to replace the `Age` by a formula for each group `('Sex', 'Pclass')` when the `Age` is null:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train_df = pd.read_csv('train_df.csv', index_col=0)
test_df = pd.read_csv('test_df.csv', index_col=0)

guess_age = lambda x: int(x.median() / 0.5 + 0.5) * 0.5

train_df['Age'] = train_df['Age'].fillna(train_df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age']
                                                 .transform(guess_age)).astype(int)

test_df['Age'] = test_df['Age'].fillna(test_df.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Age']
                                              .transform(guess_age)).astype(int)
```

Before:

```
>>> train_df['Age'].isna().sum()
177

>>> test_df['Age'].isna().sum()
86
```

After:

```
>>> train_df['Age'].isna().sum()
0

>>> test_df['Age'].isna().sum()
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like

```
train_set['Age'] = train_set['Age'].fillna(train_set.groupby(["Sex","Pclass"])['Age'].transform('median'))
test_set['Age'] = test_set['Age'].fillna(train_set.groupby(["Sex","Pclass"])['Age'].transform('median'))
```